# Error opening microsoft.com in Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, crash

I need help with my browsers. In Windows 7 Basic I have 2 browsers installed: Internet Explorer 8 and Google Chrome. When I try to open pages which are associated with Microsoft (like Live and others), my browser crashes; Internet Explorer 8 crashes too. But Opera (I've installed it later) works fine with those pages.

P.S. I tried to scan my PC for trojans and viruses, but it's clean.

Update: now I tried to uninstall the silverlight plugin. But browser still crashes when open microsoft.com/genuine/ page. And what's interesting, other web pages, which has silverlight player on it (for video whatching), opens the video correctly and doesn't propose me to install silverlight plugin. So, I think the silverlight doesn't correclty uninstalled.

Update2: tried to open the http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/1.0/page-turn/default.html page. Silverlight uninstalled correctly. So, the error has other reason.

I think errors caused with IIS 7 (ASP.Net pages)

Update3: Today I've opened www.microsoft.com/genuine/ page. It works fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer 8. So, I don't clearly understood, what was the reason of those errors. Yesterday I reinstalled Adobe Flash and Microsoft Silverlight.

Thanks to all! Closed.

Update4: Hi, again! Today, when I wrote Update3, I was at the university. And worked via proxy. Microsoft.com pages worked fine. But when I came back home, and turned off the proxy settings in the browser, problems began again...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a plug-in which is causing the crash, so you could try running the browsers with plugins and extensions temporarily disabled.

#### Chome

If you run Chrome with the command-line options `--disable-extensions` and `--disable-plugins`, does that improve things?

If you're not comfortable running Chrome from the command-line, you can right-click on the Chrome icon, choose **Properties**, and paste those options into the Target text-box:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\myname\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-extensions --disable-plugins
```

#### IE8

Similarly, you can run IE8 without extensions like this:

```
iexplore -extoff
```

Since you say that Microsoft sites are problematic, I'd suspect the Silverlight plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a virus, try a different Virus scanner.

Which Anti-virus software are you using?

EDIT:
Found [a guy with the same problem as you](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6132_102-331000.html), in his case its caused by a virus. Try see if you got the same problems as him.

Comment: I'm using 2 antivires: Microsoft Essentials and Avira.

Comment: Found this guy with some kind of same problem: http://bit.ly/a2dfTl

Comment: Now I'm searching for viruses. But PC is also clean. I think it's silverlight error. I have installed on my PC Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, .Net 3.5 SP1. So, problems begans after I installed silverlight plugin. Now I want to reinstall silverlight. But I don't know how to do it?

Comment: @Ilnur if you think it's related to Silverlight, edit your question to add more details. Also, try uninstalling Silverlight to see if the problem goes away (go to Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel and uninstall it as you would any other program).

Comment: Try using a install from Filehippo. http://www.filehippo.com/download_silverlight/

Comment: I really think its a virus, since the Microsoft Genuine site don't contain Silverlight..

Comment: @Fogh: yes! I are right. But I searched for viruses again using Norton online virus scan system. My PC is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file.

Comment: I checked the hosts file. It contains only comments (lines, which begans with # character).

Comment: @Ilnur can you please explain to us why this answer was marked as accepted? I'm not saying it's not the correct answer, I'd just like a bit more detail explaining what the problem was. This way it could also help others.

Comment: So... I newby in superuser.com (stackoverflow). And I thinked, that if I checked the solution of user, it should be checked as accepted. Sorry...

Comment: @Ilnur check the answer only if it solves your problem. Until then, feel free to upvote any answers that help you out.

Comment: OK. Thanks! 
I have only 6 points of reputation. So, I can't vote =)

Comment: @Ilnur you'll get more if you stick around, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... I also think it's silverlight error. I tried to start chrome with this options (--disable-extensions and --disable). Opened the www.microsoft.com/genuine/ page. And Chrome crashed. =(

IE 8 with -extoff option opens that page, but checking process(for legality of copy of windows OS, but page doesn't matter. I pretty sure, that other microsoft pages also would crash) could'nt began, because the activex components are disabled.

How to disable or fix silverlight plugin?